# Passing delegate array from static class

Tags: c#, delegates

I am trying to instantiate a class, which accepts array of delegates to the cunstructor(`Func<string, bool>[]`) from a static method of a static class, and it throws an exception `System.ArgumentException: Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.`

Using this array inside the static class itself causes no problem, exception only occurs when I try to pass the array.

```cs
public static class Program
{
    private static readonly MyAnotherClass MyAnotherField; // this is the error, see the answer below

    private static readonly Func<string, bool>[] UsefulMethods =
    {
        UsefulMethod1,
        // other methods
    }

    private static readonly MyClass MyClassField = new MyClass(UsefulMethods);

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClassField.Handle(); // exception occurs here
    }

    private static bool UsefulMethod1(string value)
    {
         // some logic
         return true;
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    private readonly Func<string, bool>[] Methods;
    
    public MyClass(Func<string, bool>[] methods)
    {
        // guards
        Methods = methods;
    }

    public void Handle()
    {
        // some logic
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kcnSjZ) runs without errors. Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Heinzi cannot reproduce in fiddle either, but it throws an exception in my environment (RIder IDE, target framework .netcoreapp3.1). Here is the full code [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Omwxya). Although in the example it's array of `Tuple` instead of `Func`, changing one to another doesnt make it work

Comment: Hmm... strange. Good question, but since I don't have Rider IDE, I'm afraid I won't be able to help.

Comment: @Heinzi checked VS2019, the same exception is thrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found a solution.

Example was not reproducible in the fiddle but in my environment, because of a static readonly field, I didn't include.

In the example above there also should be a field:

```cs
private static readonly MyAnotherClass MyAnotherClassField;
```

Which is not instantiated anywhere. Although I still don't understand, why exception is thrown about delegates, making this change:

```cs
private static readonly MyAnotherClass MyAnotherClassField = new MyAnotherClass();
```

makes everything work.